# Jenkins NUnit test reports are not rendering in emails

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, nunit, hudson, email-ext

I have installed the following plugins on my Jenkins:

1. [NUnit](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NUnit+Plugin)
2. [xUnit](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin)
3. [Email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)

Then I pointed the paths to my NUnit reports *.xml's in plugin settings (I tried both Nunit and xUnit plugins). After build I can see the test reports in the Jenkins web page, but I can't achieve it in emails.

What I unsuccessfully tried to do:

1. Render ${FAILED_TESTS} value in the email-ext plugin configuration. It is rendered as "No tests ran."
2. Setup ${SCRIPT, template="groovy-html-larry.template"} as template and add the following lines:

-

```
<%
    if(build.testResultAction) {
    %>
    There are some tests
    <% } else { %>
    Nothing
    <% } %>
```

unfortunately, it is rendered as "Nothing".

So the problem I can't see tests results in emails (but it is available in the web page). Have someone solved such problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround. All works ok when I use free-style project (not multi-configuration project as I used before). It seems like a bug of a plugin or Jenkins.